# TFS 2008 Merge: Merge bunch of change sets, resolve, check-in, repeat and see more changes?

Tags: tfs, merge

We have a situation like this:

1. Merge Branch Blah back to trunk.
2. Resolve all the conflicts.
3. Check everything in.
4. Without an intervening Get, we try and merge
   again. Everything should be clean,
   but it's not. More conflicts are
   found.

Why?

Tree looks like this:

A -> Branches -> X -> Blah

A -> X

Answer (score 2):

Some possibilities:

1. People were still using the source branch sometime between step 1 and step 4.
2. The parameters you passed to Merge in step 4 were different from step 1.
3. The range you were merging in step 1 contained a sequence of changes that couldn't be "played back" in the target in one step.  For example, delete Foo + rename Bar->Foo.  In cases like this, TFS will issue a warning (yellow text) during step 1.

To debug further you'd need to post the complete 'tf history -f:detailed' and 'tf merges -f:detailed' of the files you believe to be merged incorrectly.